# Can you solve the 7x7 (sudoku-ish) centered sums puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, sudoku, logic-grid, solvability

I have come across this puzzle a few times in competitions and rally's, and it has troubled me because I cannot seem to find a good approach to solving it, either programmatically or numerically. And I cannot even find traces of it online anymore, no name for it, or solution/solver.

It is basically a 7x7 grid, with 9 centers that should sum up to the cells around it:

```
# # # # # # #  
# A # B # C #  
# # # # # # #  
# D # E # F #  
# # # # # # #  
# G # H # I #  
# # # # # # #
```

the given are the numbers A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I  and you need to solve the grid with numbers from 1 to 7 such as no number is used twice on any (COMPLETE) row or column (ie: rows and columns that don't intersect with A through I)

There may be more than one solution for any given set of numbers A thru I, though I cannot confirm this 100%

I have tried solving this with excel and matlab, the matlab code simply iterates through all sets of 7x7 matrices by swapping rows and columns already filled from 1 to 7. This solution may not solve the puzzle for certain sets of numbers A thru I, as it skips many sets of possible solutions.

Here is a trivial solution found by filling up the rows and columns from 1 to 7:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 A 4 B 6 C 1
3 4 5 6 7 1 2
4 D 6 E 1 F 3
5 6 7 1 2 3 4
6 G 1 H 3 I 5
7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

In this case we have:
A = 24
B = 40
C = 35
D = 40
E = 35
F = 23
G = 35
H = 23
I = 32

EDIT:
Here is one form of the puzzle itself, you can at least try to solve this one. I have managed to obtain the solution through brute-force and 6 hours of computation, however that isn't the method I was hoping for. Good luck:

```
## ## ## ## ## ## ##  
## 15 ## 28 ## 44 ##  
## ## ## ## ## ## ##  
## 33 ## 36 ## 36 ##  
## ## ## ## ## ## ##  
## 46 ## 31 ## 19 ##  
## ## ## ## ## ## ##
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for a way to attack such problems? And are there prescribed cells apart from the sums?

Comment: If you want a programming solution I would start by understanding a [depth first brute force sudoku solver](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).  Here is an explained one in python with links to a number of other languages.  Obviously it would need some tweaks but it would be a good place to start.

Comment: I am looking for a way to be able to solve this puzzle.
Brute force solutions are generally too long of an approach that I was hoping not to tackle, but I will check out the link and see if I can get anywhere concrete with solving this puzzle.  
There are no other prescribed cells, just the 9 center cells given with the required numbers, and you have to fill all remaining cells.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question so that to include a puzzle. Then people can start answering it by sharing code fragments, insight, etc. It could very well turn out, that some sort of intelligent brute-force won't take as long as you anticipate. In practice you should start taking the integer partitions of the number A, and then B, and then D so that to fill out the entries between cells A and B, and A and D, and then move on to the next cells by keeping in mind that the full rows contain a permutation. It is tedious to program down, but I expect that will run quite fast.

Comment: Alright cool, I'm gonna add an example for people to solve and see how people came about to their solutions. And I will try to implement that in my current code which permutes all possible rows and columns. However brute force was still not the solution I was hoping for. Guess we'll just have to find out who has the brains to solve this puzzle.

Comment: I kinda want A-I to be all different numbers; otherwise why would they be different letters (and doesn't it make the puzzle more interesting)?

Comment: I think there must be a typo in the last problem. If you sum A through I you get 288. This should be 12×28 minus positions 3 and 5 in first row, last row, first column, last column plus corners. But the least you can get is if you subtract 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7 and add 1, 2, 1, 2, and that's 290.

Comment: @TheVee see my answer below for minimum and maximum values possible.

Comment: @gtwebb Thank you! Turns out I had a sign error I found thanks to your squares. So it's not a difference but sum: 12×28 – sum(A:I) = sum of every other field on the perimeter, starting in a corner. That unfortunately doesn't reveal as much about the solution as I expected it to.

Comment: @PeterTaylor there are no constraints on the numbers in rows 1, 3 and 5, note for example the square in the answer below with three 1s in the second row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite easy to formulate as a [0-1 integer linear programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) and then throw at a specialised solver. With no objective function to optimise, [`lp_solve`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/) takes less than a second to give:

```
2134567
1-1-3-5
4123756
3-5-6-4
6572431
5-6-2-3
7645132
```

If I ask it to minimise the total sum, it gives

```
2143657
1-1-3-5
3124576
4-5-7-4
7563421
5-7-2-3
6735142
```

If I ask it to maximise the total sum, it gives

```
3125674
2-1-2-7
1234576
5-5-7-5
4765123
7-4-3-1
6571432
```

That one took longest: 0.9 seconds.

I wrote a small script to try to find a solution maximising each variable individually (i.e. first it tries to find a solution with a `1` in the top-left corner; then one with a `2`; etc.) and after deduplicating results I was left with 22 solutions. This isn't even guaranteed to be a complete set of solutions (and in fact only includes one of the three solutions given above), but:

```
1234567
2-1-2-6
3124765
5-4-6-4
6572413
4-6-3-1
7653142

1234576
2-1-2-7
3125674
6-4-7-3
4672315
5-6-1-2
7653421

1234576
2-1-3-5
3124657
4-5-7-4
5673241
6-4-4-2
7564123

1235467
2-1-3-6
3124675
4-5-7-4
6573241
5-6-1-3
7643512

2134567
1-1-3-5
4123756
3-5-6-4
6572431
5-6-2-3
7645132

2134567
1-2-2-6
3214765
4-5-6-4
5672431
6-4-3-2
7564123

2134675
1-2-3-6
3215467
5-5-7-4
4763512
7-4-1-3
6573241

2134675
1-2-3-6
3215467
6-4-7-4
4673512
5-6-2-1
7652143

2135467
1-1-3-6
4123765
3-6-6-4
7643521
6-5-2-3
5674132

2135467
1-2-3-6
3214675
6-4-7-2
4672513
5-6-2-1
7653124

2135674
1-2-2-7
3214576
4-5-7-5
5674312
6-4-4-1
7562143

2143567
1-1-2-6
3124765
4-5-6-4
5672341
6-6-1-3
7635412

2143567
1-1-2-6
3124765
4-5-6-4
7562413
5-7-3-1
6735142

2143576
1-1-3-5
3124657
6-3-7-4
5673421
4-6-2-3
7653142

2143657
1-1-3-5
3124576
4-5-7-3
6572431
7-6-2-2
5736124

3124567
1-1-2-6
2143765
5-3-6-4
6572413
4-6-3-1
7653142

3124576
1-1-3-5
2143657
4-6-7-4
6735241
5-7-4-2
7654123

3124576
1-1-3-5
2143657
4-6-7-4
7635241
5-7-4-2
6754123

3124576
1-1-3-5
2143657
5-3-7-4
7563412
6-5-1-3
4673251

3124657
1-1-3-5
2143576
5-3-7-4
6573421
4-6-2-3
7653142

3124675
2-1-1-7
1234756
4-5-5-4
5671423
6-4-2-2
7564321

3125674
1-1-2-7
2143576
5-3-7-5
6574321
4-6-1-3
7651432

3214675
1-2-1-7
2134756
4-5-5-4
5671423
6-4-2-2
7564321
```

I conclude that a good part of the reason for the puzzle being so hard to do by hand is that it has too many solutions to commit to any cell values: you have to be prepared to backtrack. The lack of constraints on non-repetition in "incomplete" rows and columns doesn't help: if no repetitions were allowed there either then the `15` in the top-left would be a very strong constraint, requiring its neighbourhood to be one of the eight symmetries of

```
123
2-1
312
```

But, as you can see, thirteen of the solutions above don't have that form.

To make the answer self-contained, here's my input file for `lp_solve` with the objective of maximimising the total sum. The only values which need changing to solve a different instance of the puzzle are those in the nine lines following `/* Appropriate totals */`.

```
max: 1 x001 + 2 x002 + 3 x003 + 4 x004 + 5 x005 + 6 x006 + 7 x007 + 1 x011 + 2 x012 + 3 x013 + 4 x014 + 5 x015 + 6 x016 + 7 x017 + 1 x021 + 2 x022 + 3 x023 + 4 x024 + 5 x025 + 6 x026 + 7 x027 + 1 x101 + 2 x102 + 3 x103 + 4 x104 + 5 x105 + 6 x106 + 7 x107 + 1 x121 + 2 x122 + 3 x123 + 4 x124 + 5 x125 + 6 x126 + 7 x127 + 1 x201 + 2 x202 + 3 x203 + 4 x204 + 5 x205 + 6 x206 + 7 x207 + 1 x211 + 2 x212 + 3 x213 + 4 x214 + 5 x215 + 6 x216 + 7 x217 + 1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 + 1 x031 + 2 x032 + 3 x033 + 4 x034 + 5 x035 + 6 x036 + 7 x037 + 1 x041 + 2 x042 + 3 x043 + 4 x044 + 5 x045 + 6 x046 + 7 x047 + 1 x141 + 2 x142 + 3 x143 + 4 x144 + 5 x145 + 6 x146 + 7 x147 + 1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 + 1 x231 + 2 x232 + 3 x233 + 4 x234 + 5 x235 + 6 x236 + 7 x237 + 1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 + 1 x051 + 2 x052 + 3 x053 + 4 x054 + 5 x055 + 6 x056 + 7 x057 + 1 x061 + 2 x062 + 3 x063 + 4 x064 + 5 x065 + 6 x066 + 7 x067 + 1 x161 + 2 x162 + 3 x163 + 4 x164 + 5 x165 + 6 x166 + 7 x167 + 1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 + 1 x251 + 2 x252 + 3 x253 + 4 x254 + 5 x255 + 6 x256 + 7 x257 + 1 x261 + 2 x262 + 3 x263 + 4 x264 + 5 x265 + 6 x266 + 7 x267 + 1 x301 + 2 x302 + 3 x303 + 4 x304 + 5 x305 + 6 x306 + 7 x307 + 1 x321 + 2 x322 + 3 x323 + 4 x324 + 5 x325 + 6 x326 + 7 x327 + 1 x401 + 2 x402 + 3 x403 + 4 x404 + 5 x405 + 6 x406 + 7 x407 + 1 x411 + 2 x412 + 3 x413 + 4 x414 + 5 x415 + 6 x416 + 7 x417 + 1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 + 1 x341 + 2 x342 + 3 x343 + 4 x344 + 5 x345 + 6 x346 + 7 x347 + 1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 + 1 x431 + 2 x432 + 3 x433 + 4 x434 + 5 x435 + 6 x436 + 7 x437 + 1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 + 1 x261 + 2 x262 + 3 x263 + 4 x264 + 5 x265 + 6 x266 + 7 x267 + 1 x361 + 2 x362 + 3 x363 + 4 x364 + 5 x365 + 6 x366 + 7 x367 + 1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 + 1 x451 + 2 x452 + 3 x453 + 4 x454 + 5 x455 + 6 x456 + 7 x457 + 1 x461 + 2 x462 + 3 x463 + 4 x464 + 5 x465 + 6 x466 + 7 x467 + 1 x501 + 2 x502 + 3 x503 + 4 x504 + 5 x505 + 6 x506 + 7 x507 + 1 x521 + 2 x522 + 3 x523 + 4 x524 + 5 x525 + 6 x526 + 7 x527 + 1 x601 + 2 x602 + 3 x603 + 4 x604 + 5 x605 + 6 x606 + 7 x607 + 1 x611 + 2 x612 + 3 x613 + 4 x614 + 5 x615 + 6 x616 + 7 x617 + 1 x621 + 2 x622 + 3 x623 + 4 x624 + 5 x625 + 6 x626 + 7 x627 + 1 x541 + 2 x542 + 3 x543 + 4 x544 + 5 x545 + 6 x546 + 7 x547 + 1 x621 + 2 x622 + 3 x623 + 4 x624 + 5 x625 + 6 x626 + 7 x627 + 1 x631 + 2 x632 + 3 x633 + 4 x634 + 5 x635 + 6 x636 + 7 x637 + 1 x641 + 2 x642 + 3 x643 + 4 x644 + 5 x645 + 6 x646 + 7 x647 + 1 x461 + 2 x462 + 3 x463 + 4 x464 + 5 x465 + 6 x466 + 7 x467 + 1 x561 + 2 x562 + 3 x563 + 4 x564 + 5 x565 + 6 x566 + 7 x567 + 1 x641 + 2 x642 + 3 x643 + 4 x644 + 5 x645 + 6 x646 + 7 x647 + 1 x651 + 2 x652 + 3 x653 + 4 x654 + 5 x655 + 6 x656 + 7 x657 + 1 x661 + 2 x662 + 3 x663 + 4 x664 + 5 x665 + 6 x666 + 7 x667;

/* Variable names are xrcv where r is the 0-indexed row, c is the 0-indexed column, and v is the 1-indexed value. */
/* The variables are binary (0-1), so precisely one of each xrc* is 1, and that gives the value at (r, c). */

x001 + x002 + x003 + x004 + x005 + x006 + x007 = 1;
x011 + x012 + x013 + x014 + x015 + x016 + x017 = 1;
x021 + x022 + x023 + x024 + x025 + x026 + x027 = 1;
x031 + x032 + x033 + x034 + x035 + x036 + x037 = 1;
x041 + x042 + x043 + x044 + x045 + x046 + x047 = 1;
x051 + x052 + x053 + x054 + x055 + x056 + x057 = 1;
x061 + x062 + x063 + x064 + x065 + x066 + x067 = 1;
x101 + x102 + x103 + x104 + x105 + x106 + x107 = 1;
x121 + x122 + x123 + x124 + x125 + x126 + x127 = 1;
x141 + x142 + x143 + x144 + x145 + x146 + x147 = 1;
x161 + x162 + x163 + x164 + x165 + x166 + x167 = 1;
x201 + x202 + x203 + x204 + x205 + x206 + x207 = 1;
x211 + x212 + x213 + x214 + x215 + x216 + x217 = 1;
x221 + x222 + x223 + x224 + x225 + x226 + x227 = 1;
x231 + x232 + x233 + x234 + x235 + x236 + x237 = 1;
x241 + x242 + x243 + x244 + x245 + x246 + x247 = 1;
x251 + x252 + x253 + x254 + x255 + x256 + x257 = 1;
x261 + x262 + x263 + x264 + x265 + x266 + x267 = 1;
x301 + x302 + x303 + x304 + x305 + x306 + x307 = 1;
x321 + x322 + x323 + x324 + x325 + x326 + x327 = 1;
x341 + x342 + x343 + x344 + x345 + x346 + x347 = 1;
x361 + x362 + x363 + x364 + x365 + x366 + x367 = 1;
x401 + x402 + x403 + x404 + x405 + x406 + x407 = 1;
x411 + x412 + x413 + x414 + x415 + x416 + x417 = 1;
x421 + x422 + x423 + x424 + x425 + x426 + x427 = 1;
x431 + x432 + x433 + x434 + x435 + x436 + x437 = 1;
x441 + x442 + x443 + x444 + x445 + x446 + x447 = 1;
x451 + x452 + x453 + x454 + x455 + x456 + x457 = 1;
x461 + x462 + x463 + x464 + x465 + x466 + x467 = 1;
x501 + x502 + x503 + x504 + x505 + x506 + x507 = 1;
x521 + x522 + x523 + x524 + x525 + x526 + x527 = 1;
x541 + x542 + x543 + x544 + x545 + x546 + x547 = 1;
x561 + x562 + x563 + x564 + x565 + x566 + x567 = 1;
x601 + x602 + x603 + x604 + x605 + x606 + x607 = 1;
x611 + x612 + x613 + x614 + x615 + x616 + x617 = 1;
x621 + x622 + x623 + x624 + x625 + x626 + x627 = 1;
x631 + x632 + x633 + x634 + x635 + x636 + x637 = 1;
x641 + x642 + x643 + x644 + x645 + x646 + x647 = 1;
x651 + x652 + x653 + x654 + x655 + x656 + x657 = 1;
x661 + x662 + x663 + x664 + x665 + x666 + x667 = 1;

/* No number repeats in a row */

x001 + x011 + x021 + x031 + x041 + x051 + x061 = 1;
x002 + x012 + x022 + x032 + x042 + x052 + x062 = 1;
x003 + x013 + x023 + x033 + x043 + x053 + x063 = 1;
x004 + x014 + x024 + x034 + x044 + x054 + x064 = 1;
x005 + x015 + x025 + x035 + x045 + x055 + x065 = 1;
x006 + x016 + x026 + x036 + x046 + x056 + x066 = 1;
x007 + x017 + x027 + x037 + x047 + x057 + x067 = 1;
x201 + x211 + x221 + x231 + x241 + x251 + x261 = 1;
x202 + x212 + x222 + x232 + x242 + x252 + x262 = 1;
x203 + x213 + x223 + x233 + x243 + x253 + x263 = 1;
x204 + x214 + x224 + x234 + x244 + x254 + x264 = 1;
x205 + x215 + x225 + x235 + x245 + x255 + x265 = 1;
x206 + x216 + x226 + x236 + x246 + x256 + x266 = 1;
x207 + x217 + x227 + x237 + x247 + x257 + x267 = 1;
x401 + x411 + x421 + x431 + x441 + x451 + x461 = 1;
x402 + x412 + x422 + x432 + x442 + x452 + x462 = 1;
x403 + x413 + x423 + x433 + x443 + x453 + x463 = 1;
x404 + x414 + x424 + x434 + x444 + x454 + x464 = 1;
x405 + x415 + x425 + x435 + x445 + x455 + x465 = 1;
x406 + x416 + x426 + x436 + x446 + x456 + x466 = 1;
x407 + x417 + x427 + x437 + x447 + x457 + x467 = 1;
x601 + x611 + x621 + x631 + x641 + x651 + x661 = 1;
x602 + x612 + x622 + x632 + x642 + x652 + x662 = 1;
x603 + x613 + x623 + x633 + x643 + x653 + x663 = 1;
x604 + x614 + x624 + x634 + x644 + x654 + x664 = 1;
x605 + x615 + x625 + x635 + x645 + x655 + x665 = 1;
x606 + x616 + x626 + x636 + x646 + x656 + x666 = 1;
x607 + x617 + x627 + x637 + x647 + x657 + x667 = 1;

/* No number repeats in a column */

x001 + x101 + x201 + x301 + x401 + x501 + x601 = 1;
x002 + x102 + x202 + x302 + x402 + x502 + x602 = 1;
x003 + x103 + x203 + x303 + x403 + x503 + x603 = 1;
x004 + x104 + x204 + x304 + x404 + x504 + x604 = 1;
x005 + x105 + x205 + x305 + x405 + x505 + x605 = 1;
x006 + x106 + x206 + x306 + x406 + x506 + x606 = 1;
x007 + x107 + x207 + x307 + x407 + x507 + x607 = 1;
x021 + x121 + x221 + x321 + x421 + x521 + x621 = 1;
x022 + x122 + x222 + x322 + x422 + x522 + x622 = 1;
x023 + x123 + x223 + x323 + x423 + x523 + x623 = 1;
x024 + x124 + x224 + x324 + x424 + x524 + x624 = 1;
x025 + x125 + x225 + x325 + x425 + x525 + x625 = 1;
x026 + x126 + x226 + x326 + x426 + x526 + x626 = 1;
x027 + x127 + x227 + x327 + x427 + x527 + x627 = 1;
x041 + x141 + x241 + x341 + x441 + x541 + x641 = 1;
x042 + x142 + x242 + x342 + x442 + x542 + x642 = 1;
x043 + x143 + x243 + x343 + x443 + x543 + x643 = 1;
x044 + x144 + x244 + x344 + x444 + x544 + x644 = 1;
x045 + x145 + x245 + x345 + x445 + x545 + x645 = 1;
x046 + x146 + x246 + x346 + x446 + x546 + x646 = 1;
x047 + x147 + x247 + x347 + x447 + x547 + x647 = 1;
x061 + x161 + x261 + x361 + x461 + x561 + x661 = 1;
x062 + x162 + x262 + x362 + x462 + x562 + x662 = 1;
x063 + x163 + x263 + x363 + x463 + x563 + x663 = 1;
x064 + x164 + x264 + x364 + x464 + x564 + x664 = 1;
x065 + x165 + x265 + x365 + x465 + x565 + x665 = 1;
x066 + x166 + x266 + x366 + x466 + x566 + x666 = 1;
x067 + x167 + x267 + x367 + x467 + x567 + x667 = 1;

/* Appropriate totals */

1 x001 + 2 x002 + 3 x003 + 4 x004 + 5 x005 + 6 x006 + 7 x007 + 1 x011 + 2 x012 + 3 x013 + 4 x014 + 5 x015 + 6 x016 + 7 x017 + 1 x021 + 2 x022 + 3 x023 + 4 x024 + 5 x025 + 6 x026 + 7 x027 + 1 x101 + 2 x102 + 3 x103 + 4 x104 + 5 x105 + 6 x106 + 7 x107 + 1 x121 + 2 x122 + 3 x123 + 4 x124 + 5 x125 + 6 x126 + 7 x127 + 1 x201 + 2 x202 + 3 x203 + 4 x204 + 5 x205 + 6 x206 + 7 x207 + 1 x211 + 2 x212 + 3 x213 + 4 x214 + 5 x215 + 6 x216 + 7 x217 + 1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 = 15;
1 x021 + 2 x022 + 3 x023 + 4 x024 + 5 x025 + 6 x026 + 7 x027 + 1 x031 + 2 x032 + 3 x033 + 4 x034 + 5 x035 + 6 x036 + 7 x037 + 1 x041 + 2 x042 + 3 x043 + 4 x044 + 5 x045 + 6 x046 + 7 x047 + 1 x121 + 2 x122 + 3 x123 + 4 x124 + 5 x125 + 6 x126 + 7 x127 + 1 x141 + 2 x142 + 3 x143 + 4 x144 + 5 x145 + 6 x146 + 7 x147 + 1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 + 1 x231 + 2 x232 + 3 x233 + 4 x234 + 5 x235 + 6 x236 + 7 x237 + 1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 = 28;
1 x041 + 2 x042 + 3 x043 + 4 x044 + 5 x045 + 6 x046 + 7 x047 + 1 x051 + 2 x052 + 3 x053 + 4 x054 + 5 x055 + 6 x056 + 7 x057 + 1 x061 + 2 x062 + 3 x063 + 4 x064 + 5 x065 + 6 x066 + 7 x067 + 1 x141 + 2 x142 + 3 x143 + 4 x144 + 5 x145 + 6 x146 + 7 x147 + 1 x161 + 2 x162 + 3 x163 + 4 x164 + 5 x165 + 6 x166 + 7 x167 + 1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 + 1 x251 + 2 x252 + 3 x253 + 4 x254 + 5 x255 + 6 x256 + 7 x257 + 1 x261 + 2 x262 + 3 x263 + 4 x264 + 5 x265 + 6 x266 + 7 x267 = 44;
1 x201 + 2 x202 + 3 x203 + 4 x204 + 5 x205 + 6 x206 + 7 x207 + 1 x211 + 2 x212 + 3 x213 + 4 x214 + 5 x215 + 6 x216 + 7 x217 + 1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 + 1 x301 + 2 x302 + 3 x303 + 4 x304 + 5 x305 + 6 x306 + 7 x307 + 1 x321 + 2 x322 + 3 x323 + 4 x324 + 5 x325 + 6 x326 + 7 x327 + 1 x401 + 2 x402 + 3 x403 + 4 x404 + 5 x405 + 6 x406 + 7 x407 + 1 x411 + 2 x412 + 3 x413 + 4 x414 + 5 x415 + 6 x416 + 7 x417 + 1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 = 33;
1 x221 + 2 x222 + 3 x223 + 4 x224 + 5 x225 + 6 x226 + 7 x227 + 1 x231 + 2 x232 + 3 x233 + 4 x234 + 5 x235 + 6 x236 + 7 x237 + 1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 + 1 x321 + 2 x322 + 3 x323 + 4 x324 + 5 x325 + 6 x326 + 7 x327 + 1 x341 + 2 x342 + 3 x343 + 4 x344 + 5 x345 + 6 x346 + 7 x347 + 1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 + 1 x431 + 2 x432 + 3 x433 + 4 x434 + 5 x435 + 6 x436 + 7 x437 + 1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 = 36;
1 x241 + 2 x242 + 3 x243 + 4 x244 + 5 x245 + 6 x246 + 7 x247 + 1 x251 + 2 x252 + 3 x253 + 4 x254 + 5 x255 + 6 x256 + 7 x257 + 1 x261 + 2 x262 + 3 x263 + 4 x264 + 5 x265 + 6 x266 + 7 x267 + 1 x341 + 2 x342 + 3 x343 + 4 x344 + 5 x345 + 6 x346 + 7 x347 + 1 x361 + 2 x362 + 3 x363 + 4 x364 + 5 x365 + 6 x366 + 7 x367 + 1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 + 1 x451 + 2 x452 + 3 x453 + 4 x454 + 5 x455 + 6 x456 + 7 x457 + 1 x461 + 2 x462 + 3 x463 + 4 x464 + 5 x465 + 6 x466 + 7 x467 = 36;
1 x401 + 2 x402 + 3 x403 + 4 x404 + 5 x405 + 6 x406 + 7 x407 + 1 x411 + 2 x412 + 3 x413 + 4 x414 + 5 x415 + 6 x416 + 7 x417 + 1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 + 1 x501 + 2 x502 + 3 x503 + 4 x504 + 5 x505 + 6 x506 + 7 x507 + 1 x521 + 2 x522 + 3 x523 + 4 x524 + 5 x525 + 6 x526 + 7 x527 + 1 x601 + 2 x602 + 3 x603 + 4 x604 + 5 x605 + 6 x606 + 7 x607 + 1 x611 + 2 x612 + 3 x613 + 4 x614 + 5 x615 + 6 x616 + 7 x617 + 1 x621 + 2 x622 + 3 x623 + 4 x624 + 5 x625 + 6 x626 + 7 x627 = 46;
1 x421 + 2 x422 + 3 x423 + 4 x424 + 5 x425 + 6 x426 + 7 x427 + 1 x431 + 2 x432 + 3 x433 + 4 x434 + 5 x435 + 6 x436 + 7 x437 + 1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 + 1 x521 + 2 x522 + 3 x523 + 4 x524 + 5 x525 + 6 x526 + 7 x527 + 1 x541 + 2 x542 + 3 x543 + 4 x544 + 5 x545 + 6 x546 + 7 x547 + 1 x621 + 2 x622 + 3 x623 + 4 x624 + 5 x625 + 6 x626 + 7 x627 + 1 x631 + 2 x632 + 3 x633 + 4 x634 + 5 x635 + 6 x636 + 7 x637 + 1 x641 + 2 x642 + 3 x643 + 4 x644 + 5 x645 + 6 x646 + 7 x647 = 31;
1 x441 + 2 x442 + 3 x443 + 4 x444 + 5 x445 + 6 x446 + 7 x447 + 1 x451 + 2 x452 + 3 x453 + 4 x454 + 5 x455 + 6 x456 + 7 x457 + 1 x461 + 2 x462 + 3 x463 + 4 x464 + 5 x465 + 6 x466 + 7 x467 + 1 x541 + 2 x542 + 3 x543 + 4 x544 + 5 x545 + 6 x546 + 7 x547 + 1 x561 + 2 x562 + 3 x563 + 4 x564 + 5 x565 + 6 x566 + 7 x567 + 1 x641 + 2 x642 + 3 x643 + 4 x644 + 5 x645 + 6 x646 + 7 x647 + 1 x651 + 2 x652 + 3 x653 + 4 x654 + 5 x655 + 6 x656 + 7 x657 + 1 x661 + 2 x662 + 3 x663 + 4 x664 + 5 x665 + 6 x666 + 7 x667 = 19;

/* Variables are 0-1 */

bin x001, x002, x003, x004, x005, x006, x007;
bin x011, x012, x013, x014, x015, x016, x017;
bin x021, x022, x023, x024, x025, x026, x027;
bin x031, x032, x033, x034, x035, x036, x037;
bin x041, x042, x043, x044, x045, x046, x047;
bin x051, x052, x053, x054, x055, x056, x057;
bin x061, x062, x063, x064, x065, x066, x067;
bin x101, x102, x103, x104, x105, x106, x107;
bin x121, x122, x123, x124, x125, x126, x127;
bin x141, x142, x143, x144, x145, x146, x147;
bin x161, x162, x163, x164, x165, x166, x167;
bin x201, x202, x203, x204, x205, x206, x207;
bin x211, x212, x213, x214, x215, x216, x217;
bin x221, x222, x223, x224, x225, x226, x227;
bin x231, x232, x233, x234, x235, x236, x237;
bin x241, x242, x243, x244, x245, x246, x247;
bin x251, x252, x253, x254, x255, x256, x257;
bin x261, x262, x263, x264, x265, x266, x267;
bin x301, x302, x303, x304, x305, x306, x307;
bin x321, x322, x323, x324, x325, x326, x327;
bin x341, x342, x343, x344, x345, x346, x347;
bin x361, x362, x363, x364, x365, x366, x367;
bin x401, x402, x403, x404, x405, x406, x407;
bin x411, x412, x413, x414, x415, x416, x417;
bin x421, x422, x423, x424, x425, x426, x427;
bin x431, x432, x433, x434, x435, x436, x437;
bin x441, x442, x443, x444, x445, x446, x447;
bin x451, x452, x453, x454, x455, x456, x457;
bin x461, x462, x463, x464, x465, x466, x467;
bin x501, x502, x503, x504, x505, x506, x507;
bin x521, x522, x523, x524, x525, x526, x527;
bin x541, x542, x543, x544, x545, x546, x547;
bin x561, x562, x563, x564, x565, x566, x567;
bin x601, x602, x603, x604, x605, x606, x607;
bin x611, x612, x613, x614, x615, x616, x617;
bin x621, x622, x623, x624, x625, x626, x627;
bin x631, x632, x633, x634, x635, x636, x637;
bin x641, x642, x643, x644, x645, x646, x647;
bin x651, x652, x653, x654, x655, x656, x657;
bin x661, x662, x663, x664, x665, x666, x667;
```

Comment: PS My thanks to ffao for pointing out the error in my first attempt, which found no solutions.

Comment: I did a very simple (read: simple-minded) brute force which allowed any value to be used if it did not break the row-wise and/or column-wise set constraint until filling the last cell surrounding a clue whereupon it could use the one possible value or no value. It found 16 solutions very quickly (since they had the top row a permutation less than `1  2  3  5  6  7  4`). It then went on for (untimed) maybe half an hour and found a total of 91 solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was worried this puzzle may have several solutions to it, and maybe I had presented it wrongly, because I am only remembering this puzzle from what's left of it in my memory.
Is it possible that certain number sets can lead to a single solution? Also is it possible that by solving for all rows and columns to have no repeating numbers lead to a single solution? ie, even on rows and columns crossing the sums, no repeating number?

Comment: @ThaBomb@, I can't immediately think of a way of answering those questions which is feasible with only a desktop computer. There are on the order of \$10^{17}\$ grids and slightly more potential sequences of 9 values for the clues, so I would say that it's plausible that there are puzzle instances with a unique solution, but finding one means finding a 9-dimensional hyperplane which touches the 280-dimensional simplex of puzzle instances at precisely one point, and I'm not sure how to tackle that other than by brute force.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment response to The Vee then an answer but it could help out. In solving.

Here is the minimum value I could find of 269.  The chart is coloured by how many times you count each square.

[image]

An interesting thing to note is the sum of the *2s and *4s always total 224 since if you place a number in the *4 square you cancel out 2 *2 squares.

So the actual key to minimizing the total is to minimize the values in the *1 squares.  In this example you can see each boarder row has the numbers 1 to 5 in the *1 squares resulting in the lowest total.

Alternatively the highest value possible is 305 as shown below.

[image]

Comment: But in my comment I meant the values from the particular problem posted by the OP: (A, B, ..., I) being fixed at (15, 28, 44, 33, 36, 36, 46, 31, 19).

Comment: Wait a minute, you're right of course, your argument really discredits my observation. So hmm, where's the fault...?

Comment: Oh, I missed some signs. So the difference of (12*28 - sum of A:I) must equal the **sum** of the fields I mentioned. For example, in your second case, 336 - 305 = 31 = 3 + 6 + 3 + 7 (corners) + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1. Btw. your first case contains an error, there are two 4's in the last column.

Comment: @thevee.  Thanks for the heads up.  I cant fix it for a while since i'm no longer at my computer.  I think i can just swap the 4 and 5 in the bottom column so no change in total.

Comment: Turns out the minimum is 266 and the maximum 310. The former is for example: `3 5 1 6 2 7 4` / `7 – 7 – 3 – 5` / `2 3 5 4 6 7 1` / `6 – 4 – 4 – 6` and the rest filled to satisfy central symmetry. The latter is obtained by taking 8 minus everything.

Comment: Yes this grid is the exact way I used to spend hours on excel sheets trying to solve this problem by hand. My approach was to start from the center and outwards, since the *4 square where common to all 9 sums and would be a good place to start entering values and working your way outwards to the cells which only affect 2 or 1 summing cell.